# FakeS3 : ERROR Errno::EROFS: Read-only file system @ dir_s_mkdir - /mnt [MACOS]

Tags: ruby, rubygems, fakes3, mock-aws-s3

When fakeS3, using the license number, is used to simulate AWS S3 in MAC OS, for testing (as suggested in the [documentation](https://github.com/jubos/fake-s3#running)), the following error is received:

Command:
`sudo fakes3 -r /mnt/fakes3_root -p 4567 --license <<license-number>>`

Error Message:

```
ERROR Errno::EROFS: Read-only file system @ dir_s_mkdir - /mnt
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:239:in `mkdir'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:239:in `fu_mkdir'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:215:in `reverse_each'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:215:in `block in mkdir_p'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:200:in `each'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:200:in `mkdir_p'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fakes3-2.0.0/lib/fakes3/file_store.rb:64:in `create_bucket'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fakes3-2.0.0/lib/fakes3/server.rb:208:in `do_PUT'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/httpservlet/abstract.rb:105:in `service'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/webrick/server.rb:307:in `block in start_thread'
```

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS, the /tmp directory is used to upload the files. For example,

```
sudo fakes3 -r /tmp/fakes3_root -p 4567 --license <<license-key>>
```